# Does recursive method increase cyclomatric complexity

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

I do not have any programs installed for measuring cyclomatric code complexity at the moment.  But I was wondering does a recursive method increases the complexity?

e.g.

```
// just a simple C# example to recursively find an int[]
// within a pile of string[]
private int[] extractInts(string[] s)
{
    foreach (string s1 in s)
    {
        if (s1.ints.length < 0)
        {
            extractInts(s1);
        }
        else
        {
            return ints;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the original `int[]` in your code?

Comment: _Cyclomatic complexity_ depends on the number of independent paths in your code. Roughly translated look for branching. Recursion need not necessary imply multiple control paths. I'd hazard a guess that there is not necessarily a correspondence between recursion and high cyclomatic complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, no. There is only one linearly independent path to the recursive method in your example, so it wouldn't increase the cyclomatic complexity.

Answer (score 2):

1. Loops do increase cyclomatic complexity.
2. A loop can often be rewritten using recursion plus a guard condition.

Even if the recursive call itself would not count strictly as an increment, the guard condition does. This makes the loop and recursion+guard on par.